# Is there a standardized notation to specify network ports/ranges?

Tags: network-programming, ip, range, port, notation

I am implementing a component that receives IP addresses and port ranges from command line or configuration files. For IP addresses, I use the CIDR notation. However I'm unable to find out if there is a similar standard for specifying network ports or network port ranges.

I currently envision a simple comma-separated list of dash-separated ranges (e.g., `"3999,5001-9999"`) but I'd like to refer to some specification (RFC or otherwise) that defines it. I'm even willing to switch to a different notation as long as there is some standard to back it.

Comment: I'm not aware of any RFC, I'd go with your suggestion. AWS uses a similar way to specify ports for Security groups

Comment: It looks like the colon is the way to go in iptables. http://serverfault.com/questions/594835/what-is-the-correct-way-to-open-a-range-of-ports-in-iptables

Comment: I decided to go wih a colon in my implementation purely because my users will be used to it more due to their familiarity with iptables.